# I can't print a map with QGIS 2.8.1 and Mac OS X

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, mac, qgis-2.8

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.5 and QGis 2.8.1.

I want to print a map with Print Composer. But the Buttons "Print" or "Export as PDF" don't work for me. If I use these buttons, the window for choosing a directory or printer appears but only for 1 sec. Afterwards nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

If I want to save a QGIS Project the window for choosing a directory appears and I can choose the path. The issue is only by using Print Composer.

Comment: This looks much like a bug. You might want to file it as such with the QGIS-project.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same symptoms, though only while there is a **Label** that is set to _Render as HTML_.  The issue persists in both **QGIS 2.8.2** and **QGIS 2.10.1**, both on OS X (10.10.4).  If I _uncheck_ the _Render as HTML_ box, I'm able to import as an image format with no difficulty.  A similar issue was [reported](http://osdir.com/ml/qgis-user-gis/2013-09/msg00352.html) elsewhere as well.  I agree with @ragnvald-- this looks like a bug, and I will report it.